# Why is the file not opening?

Tags: c#, file

I can't get the file to open.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load the CSV file
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\chat.csv");

    var xml = new XElement("Chat-Log",          // To convert to XML
       lines.Select(line => new XElement("Item",
          line.Split('|')                       // indicate split
          .Select((column, index) => new XElement("Column" + index, column)))));

    xml.Save(@"C:\xml-out.xml");     // Save to XML file

    MessageBox.Show("Converted to XML");

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\xmlout.xml", FileMode.Open);
    try
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("c:\\xml-out.xml");
    }
    finally
    {
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

The above piece of code should open `C:\xml-out.xml`, right?

```
 TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("c:\\xml-out.xml");
```

I have no idea why it is not opening the file. Any clue?

I tried [various options](http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-open-file).

Comment: When I run this, it converts to file, shows a messagebox but does not open the converted file.

Comment: And is there an exception being thrown?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? is the file created but blank? What operating system are you using? If Windows 7 or above, try writing to your users folder or adjusting the permissions to make sure you can write directly to the C: drive.

Comment: Try adding a `catch` block to see what the error is.

Comment: at first I thought the file was not properly closed after the save, but the Microsoft code is very similar:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360171.aspx `root.Save("Root.xml");
string str = File.ReadAllText("Root.xml");`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I don't get any error messages (Windows 8, 64 bit). Is it because I am trying to access C:\?

Comment: @user2170746: It *might* be. I strongly suspect an exception is being thrown somewhere... are you running this in the debugger or not? Try experimenting with a relative filename of just "test.xml"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, you're opening a stream and *then* trying to create a writer for it.

If the file didn't exist before, then the call to `new FileStream(@"c:\xmlout.xml", FileMode.Open)` will throw an exception... and if the file *did* exist before, then you won't be able to open a writer to it in the following line because you've still got the file open for reading. You're also then closing the `FileStream` in the `finally` block, but never closing the `StreamWriter`, which is odd.

I expect you've probably got an exception showing which of those is actually causing the problem, but you should certainly remove the statement for the `FileStream`.

You should use a `using` statement so you don't need an explicit `try`/`finally` block:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"c:\xml-out.xml"))
{
}
```

Of course there's *then* the possibility that you don't have permission to create a file on the root of the file system...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I got rid of the try/finally block and replaced it with "using". I also changed the code, now StreamWriter is closing and the file is actually opening. Thank you!